# How can I set a Safari Browser button icon?

Tags: button, safari, crossrider

I am trying to set the icon in my Crossrider extension using appAPI.browserAction.setResourceIcon (see code) but it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
 appAPI.browserAction.setResourceIcon('buttonIcon.jpg');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike other browsers, Safari uses the extension's icon as the image for the button as [noted](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.browserAction) in the Crossrider docs and quoted here for your convenience:

> - Unlike other browsers that use setResourceIcon, the Safari button    icon uses the default extension icon as set in the IDE (**Settings** > **General Settings**).
> - For optimal appearance, the icon must be 128x128    pixels with resolution 72dpi.
> - Once set, the icon cannot be changed.
> - All transparent pixels are rendered in white and all other pixels are    rendered in black. Hence, icons that do not have any
>     transparent    pixels appear as a black square.

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]